# Django: Loading data from an API

Tags: xml, django, api, loading

I'm fairly new to Django, but I have a good grasp of the basic concepts. I have a good knowledge of Python. I've got an application, and I want to be able to load data into my application periodically (by loading a view, for now).

This data comes from an XML API on the web. For simplicity, let's say I only have one model in Django:

```
class Event(models.model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  date = models.DateField()
```

The XML I want to load matches this model very closely. As an example:

```
<nextevent>
  <title>My Conference</title>
  <location>London, UK</location>
</nextevent>
```

That XML might change, but every time I load my view, I want to load the current event and store it as an object in my Django application. For this example, I'm not concerned with checking duplicates.

My question is, where (structurally) is the best place to perform the loading of this data, and how to I programatically create these objects in Django?

*Note: I'm happy using `lxml` and `urllib` to parse and load the XML, so answers don't need to dwell too much on that aspect.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when you want the loading to happen.  If it is really a case of every time a user goes to a web page (a view) you want to query the API and put the result in the database then I'd do it in the view function.

If you want to do it periodically or not in response to an incoming HTTP request then the simplest option is to use cron to kick off a management command - put the code in app/management/commands and then use cron to run manage.py .  This has access to all the Django ORM etc.

Slightly more complicated is to just import the Django libraries into a straight Python script, which can run wherever you can run Python.

For the management command case, you can access the ORM exactly like in a normal Django view:

```
event = Event()
event.title = xml.title
event.location = xml.location
event.save()
```

Assuming that you've loaded and parsed the XML into a suitable object called xml.  If you want to be flasher, you could use the serialization framework to automatically parse and load your XML - but only if you can match the XML formats up.

Comment: Hi Malcolm, the app/management/commands and cron sounds exactly like what I need to do, but what's the syntax needed afterwards to add objects?